# where to download chrome-driver for mac 64 bit

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I get chrome-driver for mac 32 bit. But i want to download for 64 bit.

I didn't find chrome-driver for 64-bit.

Please some one help me to successfully run chrome browser in mac 64-bit using wbedirver.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 64-bit version of google chrome for OSX and as a result there is no 64-bit version of chromedriver.

****Note**** google chrome != chromium

Comment: There is now - 64-bit happened in Chrome 40

Comment: Chrome on OS X became 64-bit in Chrome 39, but at the moment there is still no 64-bit chromedriver for OS X.  It's not a problem though because the 32-bit one still works fine :)

Answer (score 1):

[chromedriver 2.25 for mac](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
You also can find chromedriver for Linux or Wins in this site.

Answer (score 0):

Not even [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/docs/platforms) shows that they have 64-bit Chrome on OS-X.  The implication from the Sauce Labs page is that you get no benefit from testing the same version of a browser on two different architectures.  If you interpret that site differently, let me know.

Comment: Brother i am talking about selenium chromedriver

Comment: I agree.  Yes you are.  Sauce labs uses it also.